# Add ID to table row with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, tr

I want to add a table row to a table each time you click on an element. The added table row should have an ID. But the ID doesn't appears in the browser.

```js
function add() {
  document.getElementById("tbody").insertRow().innerHTML = `
      <tr id="tablerow"> <!-- The ID don't work -->
        <td>
            Table row
        </td>
      </tr>
    `;
}
```

```css
#add {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#tablerow {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Table Head</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
  </tbody>
</table>
<a onclick="add()" id="add">Click to add a table row</a>
```

Comment: Aside: IDs have to be unique in the document, so you can't have the same ID on every row.

Comment: And please use `button`s for actions, not `a`s. A button does something, a link takes you somewhere.

Comment: Is the ID needed for anything? If you need the ID for passing over data to JS or something, you can just use a `data-selector` instead, so you can just scrap using ID at all in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+=` instead of `.insertRow()`:

```js
const btnAdd = document.querySelector("#add");
btnAdd.addEventListener("click", add)
let idCounter = 0;
function add() {
  document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML += `
      <tr id="tablerow${idCounter++}">
        <td>Table row ${idCounter}</td>
      </tr>
    `;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Table Head</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="add">Click to add a table row</button>
```

Note: `Id`s in **HTML** are unique, and that's why I've made a counter and attached it to Id to not repeat id for many elements which are not good, otherwise use `class='tablerow'`
Another note: `addEventListener` should be used instead of inline **HTML** *on** attribute handlers.
Another other note: use **button** instead of **link**.

Answer (score 0):

try defining tablerow as a variable, like:

```
let tablerow = 1
```

then, inside the add() function, insert a counter for your variable, like so:

```
let tablerow = 1;
  function add() {
  document.getElementById("tbody").insertRow().innerHTML = `
      <tr id=`${tablerow++}`> <!-- The ID don't work -->
        <td>
            Table row
        </td>
      </tr>
    `;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the `<tr>` element returned by [`insertRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) and manipulate that. It is recommended to use DOM methods instead of inserting raw HTML and in this case, you can call [`insertCell`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) on the row and set its [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Moreover, ids should be unique in a document, so you should use a class for the rows instead.

```js
document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const row = document.getElementById("tbody").insertRow();
  row.className = 'tablerow';
  row.insertCell().textContent = 'Table row';
});
```

```css
#add {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tablerow {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Table Head</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="add">Click to add a table row</button>
```